# Remove hover style on parent when hovering on child with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a80h6pts/1/

```
<style>
.myhover {
  width: 120px;
}
.myhover:hover p{
    color: #FED242!important;
}
</style>
<div id="divParent" class="myhover">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Text text text</p>
    <div id="divChild" class="myhover">
        <p>Example text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When my mouse activates the over for `#divParent`, I want all `<p>` tags to change color except for the `<p>` inside `#divChild`.  Then when I move my mouse to `#divChild`, I want all `<p>` tags inside it to change color and the `<p>` of `#divParent` back to their original color.

I cannot remove or change the class `.myhover` or use javascript. How can I do it only with CSS?

EDIT:

Badly, some people think i have to use js. I can use js (jquery) with a minimal impact on html/css.

Comment: Can you change the HTML structure?

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery you can use:

```js
$('#divParent').mouseover(function () {
    $('#divParent > p').addClass('hover')
}).mouseout(function () {
    $('#divParent > p').removeClass('hover')
})
$('#divChild').mouseover(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#divChild > p').addClass('hover')
}).mouseout(function (e) {
    $('#divChild > p').removeClass('hover')
})
```

```css
.myhover {
    width: 120px;
}
.hover {
    color: #FED242;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divParent" class="myhover">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Text text text</p>
    <div id="divChild" class="myhover">
        <p>Example text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As others have already noted, since there is no parent CSS selector you can't use CSS alone.

Comment: Your downvote was probably from sancho, since he appears to be downvoting all answers, as seen below in the 6 answers that got deleted by the owner.